# Block thread while uploading picture to Amazon S3 on Android

Tags: android, multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to block the current thread and wait while the picture is uploaded to S3?

My code for uploading to the S3 is already running in a Android service in its doInBackground() method (with other network calls that have to be in specific order), so it's off the main UI thread. I just want to know when the uploading is done, so I can dismiss notification and show to user that everything is uploaded/done.

I'm using SDK v2, like this:

```
TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, ctx);
TransferObserver obs = transferUtility.upload(
            S3BucketNamePhotoTEST,
            imageId + ".jpg",
            file, new ObjectMetadata());
obs.setTransferListener(new UploadListener(dbHandler, ctx, imageId));
```

Where UploadListener is a class implementing TransferListener, where in onStateChanged() method we can detect when the upload is finished:

```
public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
        if (state == TransferState.COMPLETED) {
        //do something here!
        }
}
```

That's not what I need, because my service call will be long done when that onStateChange() callback fires.

But looking at SDK v1 (that's now mostly deprecated), there was a way to block it, with:

```
TransferManager tx = new TransferManager(
           credentialProviderChain.getCredentials());
Upload myUpload = tx.upload(myBucket, myFile.getName(), myFile);
...
// Or you can block the current thread and wait for your transfer to
// to complete. If the transfer fails, this method will throw an
// AmazonClientException or AmazonServiceException detailing the reason.
myUpload.waitForCompletion();
```

This waitForCompletion() method is just what I need, but can't get to it with the newer API.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer from Amazon developer here ->
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/91

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

If your service is ending before you are able to utilize any callbacks, then you need to keep your service open, so this doesn't happen.  If you're using an `IntentService`, these are designed as kind of a "fire-and-forget" feature.
You should look at implementing a normal `Service` so you can start a task and end it when you need to via `stopSelf()`.

Check out http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingService

This will give you more control of when the service stops. You can stop the service when the Upload is complete.

Or, if you want to "hack" it, you could add a boolean member variable and block the execution using a loop, that will poll the boolean until it is true.  You can set it to True in your UploadListener method, and it should cause the service to stay open.

```
boolean mUploadComplete = false;

// Start upload.
```

Then after `obs.setTransferListener(new UploadListener(dbHandler, ctx, imageid));`

```
do {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} while (!mUploadComplete);
```

In:

```
public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
    if (state == TransferState.COMPLETED) {
        mUploadComplete = true;
    }
}
```

/////////////////////////////// ** Previous revision below **

[This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/Upload.html#waitForUploadResult()) looks like it will solve your problem.

```
UploadResult waitForUploadResult()
                        throws AmazonClientException,
                                    AmazonServiceException,
                                    InterruptedException
```

> Waits for this upload to complete and returns the result of this upload. This is a blocking call. Be prepared to handle errors when calling this method. Any errors that occurred during the asynchronous transfer will be re-thrown through this method.

so call:

```
UploadResult myResult = myUpload.waitForUploadResult();
```

That should block the thread until the upload is finished.

Comment: Sorry Andrew, but that doesn't answers my question. I need to block the thread from where I call the upload function of transferUtility. This code doesn't solve that.

Comment: But the code for uploading is already off the UI thread (on the service thread) so there is no problem in blocking it. I keep the logic for syncing in that service (not just photos, all kind of other app stuff) and it's stupid if the service is done and the user thinks all is uploaded, but uploading of photos are on some other thread waiting the callback from amazon to fire.

Comment: I was confused with what you were talking about in your OP. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I appreciate you answering my question, but this is still not the one that's good enough. This call you're mentioning, It's deprecated and should not be used anymore (as I already mentioned in the question).

Comment: I see, I cannot find any information on a V2 API.  Can you post a link to the docs so I can poke around?  Also, you should change the text in your OP to `myUpload.waitForUploadResult()` to avoid confusion.  I did read your Post, and you wrote `myUpload.waitForCompletion()`, hence the confusion. I posted the method from the docs I found, I didn't see any text mentioning it was deprecated.

Comment: That waitForCompletion() method is mentioned here -> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html

Comment: And this is the api v2 page -> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/. If you look at this page -> https://aws.amazon.com/articles/3002109349624271 it clearly say that we should use v2. In Android studio, all the Classes from v1 are deprecated.

Comment: Okay, I went to the v2 page and found the same method `waitForUploadResult()`. I went to docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc then I clicked on:
com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager, Then Upload, then under "Method Summary" `UploadResult waitForUploadResult()` This is the version 2 method you were looking for.

Comment: When I try to use UploadResult, it gives me -> "Deprecated - The Transfer Manager is now deprecated in favor of the com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferUtility"

Comment: Hmm,  okay, the docs are misleading then, I will do some searching and get back to you

Comment: Thanks Andrew, it really is driving me mad and I'm thinking of switching back to deprecated methods :/

Comment: Based on your OP, I'm guessing you're using the IntentService? I think you might have to implement the regular service class so that the service keeps running until the upload is complete, then when your upload is complete, via the UploadListener you can stop the service manually.

Comment: If you want to "hack" it you could create a boolean member variable in the service, then after calling upload, poll that boolean with a loop. Don't exit the loop until that boolean is true. Then in your on State Changed, set the boolean to true when the upload is done, this will cause the loop to exit and the service to end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101421/discussion-between-andrew-senner-and-beemo).